# Can i set a specific footer for the last page of MPDF?

Tags: php, mpdf

I'm using mpdf and wanted to have a specific footer for the very last PDF page generated.

Is this possible?

I know you can use "@page:first" to target the first page, but "@page:last" doesn't work.

Any help would be great...

Answer (score 4):

[Add the `<sethtmlpagefooter />` tag](https://mpdf.github.io/reference/html-control-tags/sethtmlpagefooter.html) at the very end of your HTML mark-up and it'll set the defined footer for the last page.

```
<htmlpagefooter name="LastPageFooter">
    Show me on the last page
</htmlpagefooter>

Really long text that expands over multiple pages
...
...
...

<sethtmlpagefooter name="LastPageFooter" value="1" />
```

Comment: Hi Jake. thanks for that. But i have this set at the very bottom, so where do i put you last bit of code?

Comment: // PDF footer content                      
 $mpdf->SetHTMLFooter(' footer for all pages');    so where do i put this ... <sethtmlpagefooter name="LastPageFooter" value="1" />

Answer (score 1):

The same problem happened to me. 
I was fixing it by using the following code after the style.

(Just think its like a variable so everything between the open and closing "htmlpagefooter" will be displayed where you insert the "sethtmlpagefooter")

```
<htmlpagefooter name="footer">
contact mail etc
</htmlpagefooter>
```

*some body contents*

```
<sethtmlpagefooter name="footer" />
```